# SharePoint 2013- custom masterpage visible for all users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

I created a own masterpage in SharePoint 2013. This mastermage is visible for me (Admin). On other sites the custom masterpage is visible. I inherited my custom masterpage to all other sites.

I created there some html code in the seattle.html this works for my account. But the normal user cann not see my custom masterpage.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: You sure you published it?

Comment: I think so. If I didnt, why does it works for me?

Comment: Because you can access files which are not published (if you uploaded them yourself) while other users can't.

Answer (score 0):

(As mentioned by Paul in the comment)

You need to publish a major version of your custom master page in order to allow non-administrator users to be able to access it.

In addition, if you make any further changes to it, always ensure that you publish a major version before sharing with end-users.

Answer (score 0):

Go to masterpages
    http://YOURSITE/_catalogs/masterpage

Find your masterpage and check it.

Check version - `Open Menu` click `View Properties` if it is minor version like 0.1 then

A) In ribbon click `Files` and `Publish`

OR

B) `Open Menu` and click `Publish this version`